# Unable to insert single quote text as key in aerospike through aql

Tags: sql, aerospike, dml, nosql

I'm trying to insert a new record with Primary key as a text which contains single quote(') through aql in aerospike. But, the query is getting failed.

Here is the query:

`insert into Namespace.set (PK, iRollNumber) VALUES('Hello\'s', 2)`

I tried different formats to insert. But it wasn't worked.

`insert into Namespace.set (PK, iRollNumber) VALUES('Hello''s', 2)`

`insert into Namespace.set (PK, iRollNumber) VALUES('Hello\\'s', 2)`

`insert into Namespace.set (PK, iRollNumber) VALUES('Hello\\''s', 2)`

and Error info:

`Un-supported command format with token -  's' 
Type " aql --help " from console or simply "help" from within the aql-prompt.`

Give me appropriate methodology to overcome this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to do this if you use one of the [supported client](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/) programming languages. aql is only meant to be a tool to do quick testing. However, this should be fixed in aql too. Seems a parsing issue.

Comment: Hi @Sunil, Thanks for your reply! Our team is using C & PHP aerospike client library to dump-in and readout the data from Aerospike. I tried the same insertion of the data through my C client and it was successful & readout the data too. But, from php, We can't able to read the data over same key which contains single or double quote.

Comment: aql went through some changes to handle quotes and double quotes. Please let me know if you are still seeing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention.

I have reproduced the issue in-house.  I could not find any workarounds.

I have opened a bug for this issue to be addressed in a future release of Aerospike.

I hope this helps,

-DM